# Why are my radio buttons in Tkinter not returning values?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am building a gui in Tkinter and found that my radiobuttons aren't working properly, specifically, they can be updated and selected normally by the user, but they return what appears to be an empty string ("") instead of the coded value.  I've written a short script with the same problem to help figure this out. When I run the following script on my machine, I can obtain the `entry1` value just fine but `btn1.get()` returns the empty string.

I am running the Anaconda distribution of Python 3.7.6 64-bit on Windows 10 using Spyder 4.0.1 IDE.

And the code:

````
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
btn1 = StringVar()

def do_something():
    val0 = entry1.get()
    val1 = btn1.get()
    print("The variable values are " + val1 + " and " + val0)
    print("The method values are " + btn1.get() + " and " + entry1.get())

rb1=Radiobutton(root,text="Euro",value = "euro",variable = btn1).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
rb2=Radiobutton(root,text="Dollar",value = "dollar",variable = btn1).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
rb3=Radiobutton(root,text="Yen",value = "yen",variable = btn1).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
label1 = Label(root, text="Input Here")
label1.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

go = Button(root, text="Print Selection", fg="white", bg="black", command=do_something)
go.grid(row=10, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()```
````

So if I enter 'this works' in the entry box and select the 'Euro' radiobutton and press the 'Print Selection' command button, here is my output:

```
The variable values are  and this works
The method values are  and this works
```

Just now I changed `btn1` to an `IntVar()` and ran a similar test printing `str(val1)` and `str(btn1.get()` and it has the same problem, the value is always 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: When I run your code from the command prompt it works just fine. When you say you switch to integers and it works, did you try testing it by selecting something other than the first radiobutton? The value 0 is special since it's the default value of an `IntVar`.

Comment: Bryan, what are you running for a set up? I have no idea why this is happening  only to me.

Comment: I don't do anything to set it up.I just ran `python script.py`.

Comment: You're right. It's not working. the value is always 0. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The problem is caused by activating the tkinter backend in Spyder as the default renderer. I was able to get the script to behave as required by going to Tools>Preferences>Ipython Console>Graphics>Graphics Backend and switching the default backend from 'Tkinter' to 'Automatic'.

Why this worked, I have no idea, but I wanted to close the question out with an answer.